# Overriding methods in Collection<T>

Tags: java, generics

I am working on a class assignment where I have a collection and it will be filtered out. For example, the filter class, which is an interface is one method (matches) which takes in T element.

In my FilterCollection class:

```
public class FilteredCollection<T> extends AbstractCollectionDecorator<T> {

Collection<T> filterCollection;
Filter<T> currentFilter;


private FilteredCollection(Collection<T> coll, Filter<T> filter) {
    super(coll);
    this.filterCollection = coll;
    this.currentFilter = filter;
}


public static <T> FilteredCollection<T> decorate(Collection<T> coll, Filter<T> filter) {
    return new FilteredCollection<T>(coll, filter);
}
```

From there I have to override methods, such as add, addall, contains, remove, etc.

With the add() method

```
@Override
public boolean add(T object)
{
    return filterCollection.add(object);
}
```

However, I need to see if the object matches whats in the filter and if it does, dont add it, if it doesnt, add it. What is the proper way to go about this?

Comment: Where is `Filter` defined? In some library, or something you created? In any case, it looks like you'd have an `if` statement in the `add` method to conditionally add based on some behavior defined in the filter.

Comment: the filter is an interface. boolean matches(T element); thats the only thing in filter. Its a separate class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether `currentFilter.matches` the object. If so, then add it. If you successfully added the object, return `true`. Return `false` otherwise.

```
@Override
public boolean add(T object)
{
    if (currentFilter.matches(object)) {
        return filterCollection.add(object);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Filter` is an interface, you need to give it an implementation. For example:

```
public class MyFilter<T> implements Filter<T> {
    boolean matches(T element) {
        if (something) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `FilteredCollection.add()` method, you could do something like:

```
@Override
public boolean add(T object) {
    if (currentFilter.matches(object)) {
        // it matches: add it
    } else {
        // it doesn't match: do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldnt work I dont need to add any methods to the Filter.java interface. If the boolean add is inside of the FilteredCollection.java class, then it wont hit matches.

Comment: @AndroidDevNoob You don't have to add anything to `Filter.java`. However, since `Filter` is an `interface` instead of a `class`, you have to give it an implementation: create a **new class** that `implements Filter`. Then, in your `add()` method **inside** your `FilteredCollection` class, you can check to see if the object you want to add matches the filter.

Comment: @timtim17, how do you know the op is not already using an implementation of Filter? Telling the op that he/she will need to implement Filter might be misleading if a valid implementation is already used. When the op initializes FilteredCollection, he has to pass a Filter already. If it is an instance, then the op is already using an implementation.